# How would I be able to attach the main camera to different characters and make them have their own movement script when they are selected?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a Unity and C# beginner and I'm working on a game for a school project. I've mainly followed tutorials so far and I've run into a problem that I feel is very specific for a tutorial to help. I've got a selection menu with a Characters game object, and within it I have 3 prefabs of the characters I want to use. My issue is that whenever the game character selects and loads into the game, the camera angle stays fixed, regardless of the prefab, which makes it awkward having prefabs of different sizes because it's either too close or too far from the character's back. One thing I should mention is that after selecting the character, a game object clone is loaded into the game scene which I'm unable to access unless the game is running, which makes it difficult to save changes. I am wondering how I could change the scripts to first off, have the camera angle be attached to the prefab, but unique to each character because there are 3, all with prefabs of varying sizes so in some cases the camera is too far and in some cases it is too close. I anticipate that this will also become an issue later down the line, when I try to assign unique movesets to each character, and different movement scripts which are able to determine the speed of the character, to make sure they can move at different speeds, so I am looking to see if there is a way to cover those 3 issues, but at the moment I am working on simply getting the camera to attach to the character prefab.

I posted a very similar problem yesterday, and someone suggested that I change the scripts slightly, which I did and I'll show you them.

Said person first of all suggested that I attach a script to attach to each of my characters, which I used and attached it to the prefabs, I'm guessing attaching it to the 'characters' or prefabs has the same effect. This is the script:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This should be set to the required camera offset for this character
    [SerializeField] Vector3 offSet;
    public Vector3 OffSet
    {
        get
        {
            return offSet;
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

It was then suggested that a new method is needed on the CameraFollow script, this is what it now looks like:

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform player;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 offSet;
    void Update()
    {   
        transform.position = player.position + offSet;
    }

    // This will allow us to change what the camera is looking at
    public void SetFollowTarget(Transform player, Vector3 offSet)
    {
        this.player = player;
        this.offSet = offSet;
    }
}
```

It was then suggested that some changes need to be made to the CharacterSelection script and this is where I started running into problems:

```
public class CharacterSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
    // We'll need a reference to the CameraFollow script to change this, though
    // you could use a singleton or some other approach to get the reference
    [SerializeField]
    CameraFollow cameraFollow;

    // Let's change this to an array of Character to easily access their properties
    public Character[] characters;
    public int selectedCharacter = 0;

    public void NextCharacter()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter = (selectedCharacter + 1) % characters.Length;
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        UpdateCameraForSelectedCharacter();
    }

    public void PreviousCharacter()
    {
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        selectedCharacter--;
        if (selectedCharacter < 0)
        {
            selectedCharacter += characters.Length;
        }
        characters[selectedCharacter].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        UpdateCameraForSelectedCharacter();
    }\\\\\\\\\

    // [...]

    // With the new property and method, it's a cinch to update the camera now
    private void UpdateCameraForSelectedCharacter()
    {
        cameraFollow.SetFollowTarget(
            characters[selectedCharacter].transform,
            characters[selectedCharacter].OffSet);
    }
}
```

This script is slightly different to what I had before, but it's still attached to my Characters Game Object with all the prefabs in it. In the script component of the Game Object, each element is populated with a prefab of the characters. One thing that I have spotted regarding the Camera Follow field in Unity, in the field it says None(Camera Follow), I'm not sure if it is supposed to be this way.

Moving on to the Load Character Script:

```
public class LoadCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    CameraFollow cameraFollow;

    public GameObject[] characterPrefabs;
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    public TMP_Text label;

    void Start()
    {
        int selectedCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedCharacter");
        GameObject prefab = characterPrefabs[selectedCharacter];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        label.text = prefab.name;

        // In the same way, we can easily update the camera on scene load
        Character character = clone.GetComponent<Character>();
        cameraFollow.SetFollowTarget(
            character.transform,
            character.OffSet);
    }
}
```

This script is attached to a Game Manager object in the actual Game Scene. I should probably mention here that using this script instead of my old one, has caused a problem which is now I cannot load into the Game Scene after selecting my character in the Selection Scene. Because of this, I still haven't been able to get past the whole clone issue and I haven't been able to see how the code performs while the game is running.

There is probably something that I misinterpreted because I am a huge unity and c# noob but if anyone could help that would be quite nice.

By the way, huge thank you to Serlite who helped make these new scripts, shame I don't know enough.

Comment: Try to make your question a little shorter and more concise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts look fine. The fixed angle thing is because, at least from the scripts provided, you're not doing anything about rotation. CameraFollow is only updating the camera's position, but is not telling the camera what to look at. An idea would be to change offset to followOffset and add a new lookOffset and your CameraFollow update could look like this:

```
transform.position = player.position + followOffSet;
transform.LookAt(player.position + lookOffset;
```

Basically followOffset will be an offset that puts the camera at a position behind the character, while lookOffset will be an offset to a point in front of the player where you want the camera to look at.

Also from what I understand, you have a script called Character which is on each player prefab. Therefore, you can edit the default values in the prefab for the offsets and save. Just make sure to put reasonable offsets and always thinking of the offset in terms of the player's forward direction, you want the camera to be put behind the player.

On each prefab, you can either have different movement scripts (if they are too different), or just one that handles all cases. Your call.

As for the scene load issue, depends on how you Load the scene. If you load additive, I don't see why it fails. You're gonna have to be more specific, i.e. give us error messages from Unity or a more precise description of the problem.